# Is there any way to have a Collection publish data in chunks on MeteorJS?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, meteor

Is there any way to have a Collection publish data in chunks on MeteorJS? I've tried doing it through the .publish function but I'm not sure how to get it working.

I kept trying last night and ended up with something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('products',function(skip,limit){
    return Products.find({},{skip:skip || 0,limit:limit || 10});
});
```

I tried putting a Session variable on the subscriber to make it update the LiveData Set (I think it does that, not sure):

```
Meteor.subscribe("products",Session.get("skip"),Session.get("limit"));
```

After the session variable changed, nothing happened though, lol.

Comment: maybe provide your attempt at the publish function so your question is more clear.

Comment: I updated the question to include what I tried last night, I didn't have much to put in the first place :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your subscribe inside a Deps.autorun block.